# Bubble up events from ember component

Tags: ember.js

I've created a component which renders html text and handles click events.

Ember Components are not bubbling up events but I would like to let clicks on links bubble up to the window and let the browser handle it.

Code tells more than 1000 words :-)

HTML

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <h1>Click the link in the following div</h1>
      {{outlet}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      {{test-a}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/test-a">
    <div class="index" {{action 'edit' on="click"}}>
        <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Click me</a>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Coffee

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.TestAComponent = Ember.Component.extend
    actions:
        edit: ->
            if event.toElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'A'
                return true # should bubble to the window but is a component
            # do something for editing here
            alert('div clicked')
            false
```

CSS

```
h1 { font-size: 1.6em; padding-bottom: 10px; }
h2 { font-size: 1.4em; }
ul { padding: 15px; font-size: 1.4em; color: green; }
.index { background-color: #666; padding: 20px; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujrZL/

Comment: With the {{action}} it won't work. Because it will perform a evt.preventDefault(). Your current code is a test, can you share what is your intent? So I can think in some solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a workaround which might be the only way currently. I don't like it because it smells a bit for me.

CoffeeScript

```
actions: ->
    edit: ->
        window.open event.toElement.href, '_blank'
```

Answer (score 4):

When you create a component set the action name of the action that should be propogated using sendAction.

```
{{test-a internalAction='myAction'}}

{{test-a internalAction='myAction2'}}
```

And from inside the component

```
 this.sendAction('internalAction');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oPAtORO/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried sendAction already and it bubbles up to the route but it's not bubbling up to the browser still. I want to let the browser handle links with all individual attribute settings.

if you remove `myAction2:function(){
      alert('action2');
    }` it should open www.example.com in a new window/tab.

Comment: I do exactly his, but it says the action isn't handling. What is this business about returning true or false? Do I have to put return false in each potential bubbling action? What if I want that action to return something else? No documentation on this, or is very unclear

Comment: Do you have an action method defined in the controller/routes above your template?